# Google Sheets shorter "IF" statement for cell range?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

Trying to make a price comparison tool for our office supply orders here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NwGo8PqUcw0BGcu2RJvOSM8djBHpZnSIdmCY9s8cvhI/edit?usp=sharing

Is there a shorter way to do this?

```
D2=MIN(H2:K2)
F2=if(D2=H2, H1, if(D2=I2, I1, if(D2=J2, J1, if(D2=K2, K1, ""))))
```

Basically just trying to print the name (from header row 1) of the merchant with the lowest price (from columns H:K)

Additionally, the formula painter doesn't like this formula, so I have to change it every time.

Need this:

```
=if(D20=H20, H1, if(D20=I20, I1, if(D20=J20, J1, if(D20=K20, K1, ""))))
```

Paints this:

```
=if(D20=H20, H4, if(D20=I20, I4, if(D20=J20, J4, if(D20=K20, K4, ""))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an index-match approach.

=INDEX($H$1:$K$1,1,MATCH(MIN($H2:$K2),$H2:$K2,0))

The first part "$H$1:$K$1" is a range of cells -Your header row where you have the vendor names. This is what we will look through to find the name of the cheapest vendor. The ",1" says you're looking in the first (in this case only) row of data in that range. Now you're looking for the column with the cheapest price which brings us to...

The second part "MATCH(MIN($H2:$K2),$H2:$K2,0)" finds an exact match for the smallest number in columns H through K and returns the column number (If column J, then the number returned is 3).

Put that all together and you get the value in the cell in row 1 column 3 of your header row with the index function.